# Query for total number of orders with the same ID

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2010

Apologies if this is simple but I have just started learning SQL. In my Access database, I have a table that displays a list of orders:

[image]

I can filter the table down to just display the `OrderID` next to the Quantity of items like this:

```
SELECT OrderID, Quantity FROM OrderItems;
```

However in the table there are multiple OrderID's that are the same. How do I tell the database to total up the quantity of orders that relate to each OrderID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is is almost how you say it. You have to group the records by id and sum up the quantities. With SQL you do the following

```
SELECT
    OrderID, <-- you get the OrderID that is grouped
    SUM(Quantity) <-- you sum the quantities
FROM
    OrderItems
GROUP BY
    OrderId <-- you group the records by OrderId
```